# Update progressbar from Task.Run generate deadlock

Tags: c#, debugging, parallel-processing, thread-safety, deadlock

I am not experienced about WinForm so probably my understanding is wrong. But I think I have implemented all the syncronization needed to syncronize the worker thread with UI thread, despite that at some point the worker thread deadlock... so my thinking is probably wrong.

This is the problematic code

```
            int progress = 0;
            for ( int index = 0; index < executions; index++)
            {
                int currentIndex = index;
                Action parallelAction = () =>
                {
                    //code that is not relevant i can comment it and get the same issue
                         
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref progress);
                    this.RefreshProgressBar(progress, executions);
                };

                if (chkParallelExecution.Checked)
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(parallelAction));
                else
                {
                    parallelAction();
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    this.Refresh();
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
```

Here what the RefreshProgressBar do :

```
    private void RefreshProgressBar(int progress, int total)
    {
        prbProgress.ThreadSafeAction( () => prbProgress.Visible = true );

        decimal percentage = ((decimal)Math.Abs(progress) / (decimal)Math.Max(Math.Abs(total), 1)) * 100m;

        if (this.prbProgress.Value > percentage)
            return;

        prbProgress.ThreadSafeAction( () => prbProgress.Value = (int)Math.Round(percentage));
    }
```

And here my utility method, ThreadSafeAction (it's an exetension method) that i have intended as a way to syncronize UI element that should be updated by UI thread :

```
    public static void ThreadSafeAction(this Control @this, Action action)
    {
        if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            @this.Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }
```

I need help in understanding what's happening, with the code above paralle processing deadlock each time and never finished. I have to report also that progress bar never show up.

Debugging the code to trying to figure it out where the deadlock is i find that the code here, is executed :
prbProgress.ThreadSafeAction( () => prbProgress.Visible = true );

but the instruction just below is never reached :
ecimal percentage = ((decimal)Math.Abs(progress) / (decimal)Math.Max(Math.Abs(total), 1)) * 100m;

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

```
int progress = 0;
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int index = 0; index < executions; index++)
{
    int currentIndex = index;
    Action parallelAction = () =>
    {
        // code that is not relevant
        Interlocked.Increment(ref progress);
        UpdateProgressBar(progress, executions);
    };

    if (chkParallelExecution.Checked)
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(parallelAction));
    else
        parallelAction();
}

if (chkParallelExecution.Checked)
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

private void UpdateProgressBar(int progress, int total)
{
    decimal percentage = ((decimal)progress / Math.Max(total, 1)) * 100m;
    if (prbProgress.InvokeRequired)
        prbProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => prbProgress.Value = (int)Math.Round(percentage)));
    else
        prbProgress.Value = (int)Math.Round(percentage);
}
```

Comment: seems that nothing changed if i execute your code i get the same issue. I would be also curious about understand what's is wrong in my solution.